# How do I order my icons with a inline-block with the figcaption at the bottom of the images

Tags: html, css

I would like to arrange my skill icons in an inline-block with the description of each skill at the bottom of each image

I have tried using flex-box for the container element then using display:inline-block for the skill-icon tag but they still seem to stay aligned. I want them on top of each other even and within an inline-block

```css
/* Skills section & Skill Icons */
    
.skill-container  {

}

.skill-icon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<section class="skill-container">
    <h1>What do I use ?</h1>
    <p>I have experience with the following Languages, Frameworks & Libraries</p>
    <!--Tech Icons-->
    <div id="skills-icons">

        <div class="skill-icon">
            <img  src='/Images/icons8-html-5.svg' height="20%" width="20%">
            <figcaption>Bootstrap</figcaption>
        </div>

        <div class="skill-icon">
            <img  src='/Images/icons8-css3.svg' height="20%" width="20%">
            <figcaption>CSS3</figcaption>
        </div>

        <div class="skill-icon">
            <img  src='/Images/icons8-javascript.svg' height="20%" width="20%">
            <figcaption>Javascript</figcaption>
        </div>

        <div class="skill-icon">
            <img  src='/Images/icons8-jquery.svg' height="20%" width="20%">
            <figcaption>Jquery</figcaption>
        </div>

        <div class="skill-icon">
            <img  src='/Images/icons8-git.svg' height="20%" width="20%">
            <figcaption>Git</figcaption>
        </div>

        <p>Currently improving ReactJS</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Above is the CSS classes that I have tried to complete this with the images keep aligning on top of each other and not side by side like I want [please see the image as this is exactly what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASHA1.png)

I would like my images to be on top of each other with a display: inline-block element

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use `<figcaption>` tag inside `<figure>` tag for correct semantics. More details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption)

Please check out the implementation below which meets your expectations.

```css
/* Skills section & Skill Icons */
    
.skill-icon {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  
  
  /* only for example styling */
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="skill-container">
    <h1>What do I use ?</h1>
    <p>I have experience with the following Languages, Frameworks & Libraries</p>
    <!--Tech Icons-->
    <div id="skills-icons">

        <figure class="skill-icon">
            <img src='https://pluralsight.imgix.net/paths/path-icons/nodejs-601628d09d.png?w=70' />
            <figcaption>JavaScript</figcaption>
        </figure>

        <p>Currently improving ReactJS</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

It doesn't matter if you are going to use `display: flex;` or `display: inline-flex` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

display flex with fixed height should wrap your skills accordingly. If you want a dynamic height then remove flex direction column.

```css
#skills-icons{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction:column;
  height:200px;
  align-items:center;
}

.skill-icon{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<section class="skill-container">
        <h1>What do I use ?</h1>
        <p>I have experience with the following Languages, Frameworks & Libraries</p>
        <!--Tech Icons-->
        <div id="skills-icons">

            <div class="skill-icon">
                <img  src='https://pluralsight.imgix.net/paths/path-icons/nodejs-601628d09d.png?w=70'>
                <figcaption>Bootstrap</figcaption>
            </div>

            <div class="skill-icon">
                <img  src='https://pluralsight.imgix.net/paths/path-icons/nodejs-601628d09d.png?w=70'>
                <figcaption>CSS3</figcaption>
            </div>

            <div class="skill-icon">
                <img  src='https://pluralsight.imgix.net/paths/path-icons/nodejs-601628d09d.png?w=70'>
                <figcaption>Javascript</figcaption>
            </div>

            <div class="skill-icon">
                <img  src='https://pluralsight.imgix.net/paths/path-icons/nodejs-601628d09d.png?w=70'>
                <figcaption>Jquery</figcaption>
            </div>

            <div class="skill-icon">
                <img  src='https://pluralsight.imgix.net/paths/path-icons/nodejs-601628d09d.png?w=70'>
                <figcaption>Git</figcaption>
            </div>

           
        </div>
         <p>Currently improving ReactJS</p>
    </section>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this! I knew I was close just could not get my head around the right css classes!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>In Snippet it won't show but this will work for you.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <div class="row p-2">
            <div class="col d-sm-flex justify-content-xl-center">
                <figure class="figure"><img class="img-fluid figure-img mt-1" style="width: 85px;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/1200px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png">
                    <figcaption class="figure-caption d-sm-flex justify-content-sm-center">HTML</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="col d-sm-flex justify-content-xl-center">
                <figure class="figure"><img class="img-fluid figure-img mt-1" style="width: 85px;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/1200px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png">
                    <figcaption class="figure-caption d-sm-flex justify-content-sm-center">HTML</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="col d-sm-flex justify-content-xl-center">
                <figure class="figure"><img class="img-fluid figure-img mt-1" style="width: 85px;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/1200px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png">
                    <figcaption class="figure-caption d-sm-flex justify-content-sm-center">HTML</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="col d-sm-flex justify-content-xl-center">
                <figure class="figure"><img class="img-fluid figure-img mt-1" style="width: 85px;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/1200px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png">
                    <figcaption class="figure-caption d-sm-flex justify-content-sm-center">HTML</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row p-2">
            <div class="col d-sm-flex justify-content-xl-center">
                <figure class="figure"><img class="img-fluid figure-img mt-1" style="width: 85px;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/1200px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png">
                    <figcaption class="figure-caption d-sm-flex justify-content-sm-center">HTML</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="col d-sm-flex justify-content-xl-center">
                <figure class="figure"><img class="img-fluid figure-img mt-1" style="width: 85px;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/1200px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png">
                    <figcaption class="figure-caption d-sm-flex justify-content-sm-center">HTML</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="col d-sm-flex justify-content-xl-center">
                <figure class="figure"><img class="img-fluid figure-img mt-1" style="width: 85px;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/1200px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png">
                    <figcaption class="figure-caption d-sm-flex justify-content-sm-center">HTML</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="col d-sm-flex justify-content-xl-center">
                <figure class="figure"><img class="img-fluid figure-img mt-1" style="width: 85px;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/1200px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png">
                    <figcaption class="figure-caption d-sm-flex justify-content-sm-center">HTML</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#skills-icons{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction:column;
  height:200px;
  align-items:center;
}

.skill-icon{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<section class="skill-container">
        <h1>What do I use ?</h1>
        <p>I have experience with the following Languages, Frameworks & Libraries</p>
        <!--Tech Icons-->
        <div id="skills-icons">

            <div class="skill-icon">
                <img  src='https://pluralsight.imgix.net/paths/path-icons/nodejs-601628d09d.png?w=70'>
                <figcaption>Bootstrap</figcaption>
            </div>

            <div class="skill-icon">
                <img  src='https://pluralsight.imgix.net/paths/path-icons/nodejs-601628d09d.png?w=70'>
                <figcaption>CSS3</figcaption>
            </div>

            <div class="skill-icon">
                <img  src='https://pluralsight.imgix.net/paths/path-icons/nodejs-601628d09d.png?w=70'>
                <figcaption>Javascript</figcaption>
            </div>

            <div class="skill-icon">
                <img  src='https://pluralsight.imgix.net/paths/path-icons/nodejs-601628d09d.png?w=70'>
                <figcaption>Jquery</figcaption>
            </div>

            <div class="skill-icon">
                <img  src='https://pluralsight.imgix.net/paths/path-icons/nodejs-601628d09d.png?w=70'>
                <figcaption>Git</figcaption>
            </div>

           
        </div>
         <p>Currently improving ReactJS</p>
    </section>
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Check Out the result in this image